# How to give permission to admin and author for view specific page in django?

Tags: python, django

right now my this code only allow it's original author to view an specific page. If author id and user id not same then it will return 404 page. here is my code:

```
def get_object(self):
          obj = super(BlogListMyAccount,self).get_object()
          if obj.author  != self.request.user:
              raise PermissionDenied      
          return obj
```

how to add permission for admin above code. so admin also can view the page.

Comment: Post some code.. esp the view that renders individual blog posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example:

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = super(BlogListMyAccount,self).get_object()
    if obj.author  != self.request.user and not self.request.user.is_superuser:
       raise PermissionDenied      
    return obj
```

Usually this is how you check if the user have admin permissions: `request.user.is_superuser`.

References:

> https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+check+if+user+instance+is+admin+django+permissions

Comment: mseromenho it's worked. I also tried to use `and  self.request.user.is_superuser` but didn't work.  After adding not as you mentioned it worked. Can you explain little bit why it work after adding not. Normally not means if he is not superuser.

Comment: @boyenec Thanks for the vote and accepted answer. In this context, we're saying "it only raises PermissionDenied if the 2 conditions are true". Only when "the user is NOT author and NOT admin" it will raise the error. If you don't use NOT before self.request.user.is_superuser you're saying that if "the user is not Author and the user is Admin", or vice-versa, to raise the error and that's not what you want. Hope this explanation was helpful.